# Multiple Standard Actions With High Base Attack Bonus

Tags: dnd-3.5e, actions

A friend and myself were having a discussion and we had a small disagreement about a rule. He says that if he has a high base attack bonus, say 20/15/10/5, and has a special ability that is activated as a standard action that he can use it 4 times on his round similarly to a full attack action. My argument is that the high base attack bonus only applies to attacks. He says that since a single attack is a standard action the 4 attacks can be replaced by standard actions.

More specifically he says that his god character can use the Hand of Death salient divine power 5 times in a round, 4 for base attack bonus and 1 for haste.

Which one of us is right?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The short answer is that you are right. In your turn you may make 1 standard action and a move action, or a full round action, along with one or more free actions - [source](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm)

A single attack is a standard action, as is using an ability. When used as such you get a single standard action, plus a move. That means you can only use your ability once per round (certain abilities may have limits on number of times per day or length between uses) - [source](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#standardActions)

When using your BAB to get more than one attack, you don't get as many standard actions as you have attacks in your BAB, but take a full round action. This is the same if you get multiple attacks from BAB, or whether it's from a haste spell, or from a double weapon, such as a quarter-staff. Other abilities that specifically say 1 round for time it takes to complete, rather than standard, also use a full round action. - [source](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#fullRoundActions)

TLDR; Your BAB only counts for a full round action, it doesn't give you many standard actions.

Answer (score 9):

### You are right.

A high BAB does not grant additional standard actions in a combat round.

The logical error he (perhaps understandably) makes is that he assumes that it being possible to take an attack as a standard action implies that you can take a standard action in place of an attack (or "attack action" as the term is sometimes used). But it doesn't.

Carefully reading over the [Actions in Combat](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm) section will reveal this (and is a good exercise in general). There is no defined way to convert a bonus attack into a standard action. Instead, the issue is handled by defining the ways a character can make attacks, and those ways include taking a standard action (which grants one) and taking a full-round action (which may grant many).

Finally, for the specific example of the Hand of Death - that ability [defaults to a standard action](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/divine/divineAbilitiesFeats.htm#salientDivineAbilities) and thus can not be used multiple times in a round by virtue of having a high BAB.