# Can a wizard cast two spells by taking a full round action?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, wizard, actions

If a wizard does not move can he cast a second spell in his turn the way melee characters can take extra swings? Also if so, can he still use a quickened spell for a total of three a turn?

I have a level 15 wizard/abjurant champion and was wondering how it worked.

Comment: @TuggyNE I don't think it's a dupe, but it's similar in terms of understanding the action economy.  That question has to do with melee attacks, and this one with spell casting ... seems different enough to me.

Comment: [Related] (Pathfinder): [Can a magus with a high BAB cast two spells or attack and cast, with their full attack action?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51194)

Answer (score 11):

Spells usually take a swift, immediate or standard action to cast (or more).

I know no spells that can be cast as a move action and this, together with the fact that quickened spells are swift actions (errataed from free as soon as swift actions were born), means that **the total number of spells you can cast per round is two** (one standard, one swift), except for effects that increase the duration of your round (e.g. *time stop*, *Belt of Battle*)

Nothing allows the wizard to spend his movement doing something magical instead, so that time is usually spent drawing wands or scrolls or actually moving.

Conversely, a wizard who can't take full round actions is not hampered at all.

You, as an abjurant champion gish, can still cast one (swift/quickened) spell per round and make full attacks at the same time.

Comment: Minor nitpick: a wizard 15/abj champ 5 has a BAB of 12, so it's not really a gish as such.

Comment: If it's really important to you, you could use contingencies or Simbul's Spell Sequencer to "cast" more spells. With a different build, you could also take levels in Beholder Mage and cast many more spells/round.

Comment: thank you.  i have very limited time in d&d so far and try and learn what i can where i can.  also is helpful because (for reasons beyond me) i became a dm after only playing enough in game time to advance two characters from levels 5 to 6 because that dm kept wanting to change campaigns.  so i got frustrated and said to hell with it i got stories, lol.

Answer (score 3):

### Normally no...

Casting a spell is a standard action (usually). You do not get extra standard actions just from more base attack bonus (or more caster level), so you don't normally get more spells.

### But sometimes yes!

This is 3.5 we're talking about, so there are always exceptions, in the form of powerful abilities. You may not be able to take them on your current character, but there's always next time (or retraining).

- **Multivoice** (feat) allows you to cast two spells per round, as a full-round action. The caveat: you need to have two heads! Also the prerequisites are very steep. But two spells per round!
- **Arcane channeling** (Duskblade level 13 ability) allows you to cast a touch-range spell into your weapon, and then full attack with it, affecting everybody you hit with that touch-range spell.
- **Quiescent weaving** (War Weaver level 2 ability) allows you to pre-cast buff spells, and activate them as a move action. This caps out at four pre-cast spells of level 5 or lower.
- **Schism** (telepath level 4 psionic power) gives you an extra mind that can take an extra purely mental standard action every round. While it couldn't cast a spell with components, it could cast, for example, a *silenced dimension door* because that is a spell with no components. This is useful if you are a character such as a cerebremancer, who can cast spells and manifest psionic powers at the same time.
- **Perpetual options** (Swiftblade level 9 ability) grants you an extra standard action every round you're under the effects of *haste*.

No other such abilities come to mind at the moment, beyond weird ones possessed by monsters.

Comment: While not highly recommended for the most part you also gain spell channeling from the spellsword prestige class from complete warrior.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Zachiel comprises all the basic information.

I just want to add that your character is only one level away from casting three spells per round, though it has nothing to do with taking full round actions or not moving. In fact, you could double move and cast three spells.

*The following information has been updated and improved by virtue of comments from Zachiel and HeyICanChan:*

Once you get your next level of spellcasting you can Shapechange (Wiz/Sor 9) into a Chronotyrin. (Fiend Folio, p. 33) This CR 19 creature has the supernatural quality of dual actions: two rounds worth of actions each round. Shapechange grants all supernatural qualities - there you go casting two full round or standard action spells per round plus one swift/immediate.

Until 2012 the other option was to Shapechange into a Choker - but that creatures supernatural quality "quickness" has been canceled by a reprint of the MM.